# App standby and emulator

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to set an app in standby mode with Android emulator? I tried with adb commands (set-inactive and get-inactive), but the idle state is always false.

Comment: Even with nexus 5x running commercial version of Android 6.0, "am set-inactive" command won't work, it returns always false.